# Google domain name HTTPS errors on single router only

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, certificate, https

Every time I browse to google.com or my local google (google.com.sg), I get an HTTPS error which on Chrome is `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. The certificate that is returned appears to be for the domain `*.googlevideo.com`.

Same thing happens in all browsers. I'm running Windows 10, and I've tried Google, Firefox and Edge. I thought I might just have some malware or something, but it happens on my Ubuntu dual boot as well, Firefox and Chrome, and it occurs on my Galaxy tablet and Macbook.

When I take my Macbook to work and connect to wifi there, it does not occur. So I feel like it's something to do with my routers or the connection to my house.

I'm able to get around it by changing the country code to one of the various other domains. Works fine in

```
google.ca
google.com.au
google.co.nz
```

**EDIT**

So it appears to work fine when I connect to one of my routers, but not when I connect to the other I've just discovered.

My router setup is a little strange and I'm not exactly a network expert so there may be something wrong here. I've got 1 ASUS router connected to my fibre line, which is running WiFi on SSID "A" and "A 5G". It's in a cupboard though, so the receptions not amazing in my room. For that purpose I have a second TP-LINK router connceted over ethernet to the ASUS router. It's also running WiFi but on SSID "B" and "B 5G". All of my computers/devices connect to "B" or "B 5G" when I'm in my room, otherwise they connect to "A" or "A 5G".

I'm using the TP-LINK router as a bridge (I think that's what it is?) so it receives it's internet connection from the ethernet to the ASUS router. Both routers have different IP ranges.

TP-LINK router is on 192.168.0.1 (leases up to 192.168.0.254)

ASUS router is on 192.168.2.1 (leases up to 192.168.2.254)

The TP-LINK router has the WAN IP (again not sure that's the correct terminology) of 192.168.2.16 which is permanently set in the ASUS router. The ASUS router has a proper external IP from my ISP.

My Macbook/tablet both run from Wifi but my desktop is wired directly to the TP-LINK router.

The TP-LINK router is the one having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the few symptoms of an HTTP [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) but not the only possible cause. It is difficult to diagnose without strong networking knowledge.

If using wifi; is it your access point or another with the same name? This is the most common attack vector.

Some router firmware is vulnerable to attack. Best to contact your ISP, some can remote diagnose and update your firmware.

Problems further upstream are rare and shouldn't last more than a few hours.

Comment: Thanks, I remembered when you said "another with the same name" that my router actually runs through another router. I've added additional info to my question. Google works perfectly by connecting to my other router, so it must be a router issue?